# How to plot multiple measures on a line chart with shared axis and legend

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two line plots that come from a different columns in measurement formulas but both share the time axis.

This is the first plot:

[image]

The second one:

[image]

In this case the second plot is just a scaled version of the first one, but the principle remains the same, I´m not able to just drag and drop the values from both measurements into the same "valores" box, it just iverwrites:

[image]

How can I plot this two measurements on the same box? 
Something like the stacked areas plot but without the offset.

This is my data:

[image]

And the expresion fot the measurements I´m using:

```
Medida = CALCULATE(sum(test_data[Percentage_By_Class]);filter(test_data;test_data[Date]=max(test_data[Date]));
ALLEXCEPT(test_data;test_data[Score]))/ CALCULATE(sum(test_data[Percentage_By_Class]);
filter(all(test_data);test_data[Date]=max(test_data[Date])))


Medida2 = CALCULATE(sum(test_data[Percentage_By_Class]);filter(test_data;test_data[Date]=max(test_data[Date]));
ALLEXCEPT(test_data;test_data[Score]))/ CALCULATE(1.3*sum(test_data[Percentage_By_Class]);
filter(all(test_data);test_data[Date]=max(test_data[Date])))
```

And a google drive link to download the used data in CSV format:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEdUwwofv1OQ9rOGQMuyfYKO9_YJDTcl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The line plot is just like the stacked area plot, without the stacking. I'm not sure I understand why that's not working for you.

Comment: @AlexisOlson The problem is that I have two different measurements and I can not drag and drop both of them on the same plot

Comment: @AlexisOlson I have edited the question to add more details.

Comment: Both plots look the same to me.

Comment: I just scaled one, but the point is not the shape oficina this plot but how to merge it si it works for any other plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a nice built-in way to do this, but here's a possible workaround:

Create a new table for the legend which will be the Cartesian product of scores and measures.

```
Legend =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CROSSJOIN(VALUES(test_data[Score]), {1,2}),
    "Legend", [Score] & [Value]
)
```

This table should like this:

```
| Score | Value | Legend |
|-------|-------|--------|
| A     |   1   |   A1   |
| C     |   1   |   C1   |
| B     |   1   |   B1   |
| A     |   2   |   A2   |
| C     |   2   |   C2   |
| B     |   2   |   B2   |
```

Now create a combined measure that switches between `[Medida]` and `[Medida2]`:

```
Combo = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(Legend[Value]) = 1,
    CALCULATE([Medida], test_data[Score] in VALUES(Legend[Score])),
    CALCULATE([Medida2], test_data[Score] in VALUES(Legend[Score]))
)
```

Then if you put `Legend` in the legend box and `Combo` in the values box, you should get a chart like this:

[image: Combo Chart]

You can change the colors too if you want to visually group the lines.

[image: Chart Recolored]